# Comparing $\sin 1$ with $1$

Tags: trigonometry

I don't quite understand how this is done. If possible, please give a full explanation since I'm new in trigonometry.

> $\sin 1$ and $1$

I've thought that 1 stands for radians , is that true?

Comment: Do not understand the question. Are you sure you know what the function $\sin$ is?

Comment: not much, can you explain about this please

Comment: Comparing them as in which is greater than the other?  Do you know the range of the sine function?

Comment: yeah it's asked which is greater. the sine range [-1,1]

Comment: @Ryuzaki It's usually best to wait a day or two before accepting an answer.  That way, more people have a chance to submit and improve their answers and you can ultimately select the best one out of those.

Comment: I see, that's my 3rd day on this site, thank you for you commitment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\sin x = 1$ if and only if $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k$ for some $k$, and $1$ is not of this form, we must have
$$\sin 1 < 1.$$

Answer (score 2):

If one looks at $f(x)=\sin(x)$, the maximum occurs at 90 degrees or $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians. Remember that $\sin$ is usually computed as $\frac{y}{r}$ so in going around a unit circle it is at the point $(0,1)$ that sine will have its maximum value.

In either case, this isn't $1$ and thus, $\sin(1)<1$ would be the conclusion whether degrees or radians are used.

The lack of stating a unit would lead me to guess radians are being used though in a classroom setting I'd be inclined to confirm this rather than just leave it as an unanswered assumption.

Answer (score 0):

A graphical way to think about the problem.
$$
\sin: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}
$$
(Note  I have defined the range to be a proper superset of $[-1,1]$, otherwise you already have the answer.)
$\sin (x),$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$, graphically, gives you the length of the vector of the projection on the $y$ axis of a point on the unit circle, therefore it cannot be bigger than 1, but it may equal 1 (in particular anytime $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k2\pi$,  $k\in\mathbb{Z}$).